# SQL Server clause issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Select Name, contact, and postal code of the customer who has done MAXIMUM transactions in the month of June.

```
SELECT 
    Customer.customer_name, 
    Customer.customer_email, 
    Customer.customer_postcode
FROM
    Customer
INNER JOIN 
    Sales on Customer.customer_id = Sales.customer_id
WHERE 
    MAX(Sales.customer_id) IN (SELECT COUNT((sales.customer_id)) AS 'transactions'
                               FROM sales
                               GROUP BY (sales.customer_id)) 
    AND MONTH(date_purchased) = 6;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

Comment: You have added a condition (`and month(date_purchased)=6`) after the GROUP BY clause instead of at the end of the WHERE clause and there is also a second FROM clause. You should add a join clause to the first FROM clause.

Comment: `MONTH(date_purchased)` This will include transactions from ANY YEAR so long as the month is June. Is that really the logic you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the MAX of the customer_id, but what you want is the customer_id with the highest number of transactions. Start with your inner query, and get the top customers using `ORDER BY..DESC`.

```
SELECT Sales.customer_id, count(Sales.customer_id) as transactions
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Sales.customer_id
ORDER BY transactions DESC;
```

Now that you have the top customer_id, you should be able to join that result on the Customers table (using this as a CTE or an inner query) to get the name, contact, and postal code.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query has a number of issues:

- Aggregates such as `MAX` cannot be used in the `WHERE`, they must be in the `HAVING` part.
- Even if you change it to `HAVING`, the subquery is wrong because it doesn't filter on June
- A much simpler method is to just join the tables, group, and then sort by `COUNT` and take the first row
- The outer June filter should use start and end dates, not `MONTH` function, to improve performance
- You should use proper table aliasing

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
    c.customer_name, 
    c.customer_email, 
    c.customer_postcode
FROM
    Customer c
INNER JOIN 
    Sales s on Customer.customer_id = Sales.customer_id
WHERE 
    date_purchased >= '20200601' AND date_purchased < '20200701'
    -- note the use of half open interval >= AND <
GROUP BY
    c.customer_name, 
    c.customer_email, 
    c.customer_postcode
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```